# Out of Bound Exception when using parallel solving in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing

I am trying to solve multiple optimization instances in parallel and created a toy example. When I solve each instance with a single thread, it works fine. When I start increasing the number of threads, I receive out of memory exception for some instances. I was wondering if someone could give me a hint on how to fix this issue.

I tried my best to make the example as simple as possible.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Vector;

public class ConcurrentExample {
    public static int fixed;
    public static int nbWarehouses;
    public static int nbStores;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IloException, InterruptedException {
        int nProblems = 20;

        final Vector<Integer> v = new Vector<Integer>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= nProblems; ++i) v.add(i);

        final Iterator<Integer> it = v.iterator();
        int nTHREADS = 2; //numofCores
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[nTHREADS ];

        for (int t = 0; t < nTHREADS ; ++t) {
              threads[t] = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    int i;
                    synchronized (it) {
                      if ( !it.hasNext() ) return;
                      i = it.next();
                    }
                    fixed = 400 + i;
                    nbWarehouses = 400 ;
                    nbStores     = 800 + i;
                    int[] capacity = new int[nbWarehouses]; 
                    int[][]  supplyCost= new int[nbStores][nbWarehouses]; 
                    for(int w=0; w< nbWarehouses ; w++) {
                        capacity[w] = (nbStores/ nbWarehouses) + (w % ( nbStores/ nbWarehouses));
                        for(int s=0; s< nbStores ; s++) {
                            supplyCost[s][w] = 1 + ( ( s + 10 * w) % 100 );
                         }
                    }
                }
               }
            }
          );
        }

        for (int t = 0; t < nTHREADS; ++t) { threads[t].start(); }

        for (int t = 0; t < nTHREADS; ++t) { threads[t].join(); }


    }

}
```

When I use two threads, I receive the following error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 801
    at concurrent$1.run(concurrent.java:36)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

When I set `NTHREADS=4`, then I receive the following error.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" Exception in thread "Thread-0" Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 802
    at concurrent$1.run(concurrent.java:36)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 801
    at concurrent$1.run(concurrent.java:36)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 803
    at concurrent$1.run(concurrent.java:36)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

EDIT: One very important thing is that I have to keep the variables as globally defined. This is just a toy example. In the real model, I have static variables which are accessed by multiple methods during an iterative solution approach.

Comment: You really should follow proper Java naming conventions, it would make it much easier to understand what is going on.  Classes `ShouldBeLikeThis` and variables `shouldBeLikeThis`.  You have it backwards.

Comment: @Nexevis Sorry for the inconvenience. I updated my post accordingly.

Comment: Also, what line is line 36 (the line causing the issue)?

Comment: @Nexevis Yes. It looks like when I remove line 36, the problem seems to be solved. In essence, I have an optimization model which is solved by ```CPLEX```.

Comment: Which line is that though?  There are no line numbers for us (and your line numbers could be different).

Comment: how big are the `capacity` and `supplyCost` arrrays?

Comment: @Nexevis My bad. The line is ```supplyCost[s][w] = 1 + ( ( s + 10 * w) % 100 );```

Comment: @Shark They change at every iteration based on ```` fixed = 400 + i; nbWarehouses = 400 ;  nbStores     = 800 + i;``` where ```i``` goes from 1 to 20.

Answer (score 0):

When two threads started, "nbStores" may be incremented, through which iteration done on line 36 may get ArrayIndexOutOfException.

First thread starts with 
  int[][]  supplyCost= new int[nbStores][nbWarehouses];//nbStores=801
Once second thread started, nbStores will become 802, which may affect the loop to run till s=801.
        for(int s=0; s< nbStores ; s++)

Answer (score 0):

Why use so many static field? There will be no problem if you use local variables:

```java
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Vector;

public class ConcurrentExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        int nProblems = 20;

        final Vector<Integer> v = new Vector<Integer>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= nProblems; ++i) v.add(i);

        final Iterator<Integer> it = v.iterator();
        int nTHREADS = 2; //numofCores
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[nTHREADS];

        for (int t = 0; t < nTHREADS ; ++t) {
            threads[t] = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    while (true) {
                        int i;
                        synchronized (it) {
                            if ( !it.hasNext() ) return;
                            i = it.next();
                        }

                        int nbWarehouses = 400 ;
                        int nbStores     = 800 + i;
                        int[] capacity = new int[nbWarehouses];
                        int[][]  supplyCost= new int[nbStores][nbWarehouses];
                        for(int w=0; w< nbWarehouses ; w++) {
                            capacity[w] = (nbStores/ nbWarehouses) + (w % ( nbStores/ nbWarehouses));
                            for(int s=0; s< nbStores ; s++) {
                                supplyCost[s][w] = 1 + ( ( s + 10 * w) % 100 );
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            );
        }

        for (int t = 0; t < nTHREADS; ++t) { threads[t].start(); }

        for (int t = 0; t < nTHREADS; ++t) { threads[t].join(); }


    }

}
```

Comment: Is it possible to handle this issue while keeping the variables still globally defined?